# Windows 10 blue rectangle when dragging window

Tags: windows-10, window, touchscreen

When I drag a window on my Windows 10 laptop I get this blue rectangle that appears that follows my mouse around and lets me snap the window to a portion of the screen.

[image: Blue rectangle when dragging window]

I suspect that it may have to do with the fact that my laptop has a touchscreen and that it's supposed to make it easier to dock windows, but I don't really know.

Does anybody know how to get rid of this?

Comment: Thanks @davidpostill, I didn't know the name of it so couldn't find the dupe :).

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the blue box by turning off the narrator (cap lock+esc).

[Source:](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/blue-outline-on-everything-i-click-on/cca92fa8-3207-4572-900b-9b6fe5ea0f1c?auth=1)

Comment: It's not a blue rectangle around what I click, it's a rectangle that hovers near my mouse when I drag a window. It's unrelated to the narrator. I think it may have to do with the fact that my laptop has a touch screen (to make it easier to dock windows) but I don't really know.

Comment: For me it was the narrator and the search for "blue rectnagle follows focus" took me here.  So you solved my problem if not the OP's.